# Pycharm not showing autosuggestion for available functions for xml.dom.minidom API

Tags: pycharm, autosuggest

import xml. dom. minidom

docs = xml. dom. minidom.

My query is on pressing in xml. dom. minidom. after pressing dot after minidom not getting autosuggestions for available functions.

I have reinstall pycharm, currently using 2020.3.3 Pycharm version.

Answer (score 0):

This is known bug in Pycharm which reproduces with many modules and packages. And I believe it is still under progress for a [verifiable fix](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-41791).

Some suggestions which you might have already seen/tried but still worth mentioning since it often fixes the issue:

1. Go to file->Invalidate cache/ Restart
2. Mark the importing file as a source by-
   File->Settings->Project Structure-> Select file and mark as Source and follow 1 again
3. Reloading the interpreter of your project in case you are using multiple python versions (Although, this bug is independent of the interpreter, I have tried with different versions myself)

**Edit:**

If none of this works, install the [early access pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/) version which has the fix for the bug.

Comment: thanks for your answer but still this is not resolving my issue :(

Comment: I am using pycharm version 2020.3.3 and python version 3.9

Comment: Install the early access version which has the fix.
[Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/) is the link.

This will work for sure.

Comment: Oh, Just  make sure you use Pycharm python interpreter/ have the libraries in your custom interpreter

Answer (score 0):

Known issue, please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-46355 (thumbs up near the title)